# Spatial join of polylines

Tags: performance, algorithm, indexing, geometry

## Task

Given a set *S* with *|S|* = *N* multipolylines perform a distance-based spatial join, joining polylines with distance *d* < *d<sub>limit</sub>*. The distance *d(i,j)* between two multipolylines *L*<sub>*i*</sub> and *L*<sub>*j*</sub> ist defined as the smallest distance between two points *p*<sub>*v*</sub> ∈ *L*<sub>*i*</sub> and  *p*<sub>*w*</sub> ∈ *L*<sub>*j*</sub>.

## Example

Given the following set of three polylines, *A* and *B* should be joined.
[image: Example]

## Simple solution

The trivial solution checks for every point *p*<sub>*k*</sub> ∈ *L*<sub>*s*</sub> if the distance of any other point *p*<sub>*m*</sub> ∉ *L*<sub>*s*</sub> is smaller than *d<sub>limit</sub>* and joins *L*<sub>*s*</sub> with the multipolyline containing *p*<sub>*m*</sub> if the criterion is fulfilled.

## Problem

The simple solution is very slow for large *N*.

## Idea

Build some kind of index to accelerate the spatial join.

## Question

What is the best way to index *S* for this task.

Comment: Beware that the point-to-point distance may not be the right criterion when the segments are long: think of a T junction.

Comment: A T junction should be joined. The distance would be 0, hence it would be joined. Or did I missunderstand you?

Comment: The distance between the end points can be large, even if the segments touch.

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. But as I'm using roadmap-data this case is very unlikely since _d-limit_ will be somewhere around 1km.

Comment: What is the point density ?

Comment: A road has a node every 10m to 100m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed-radius near-neighbor searches are readily accelerated with a [2-D tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree).

For every node, you will efficiently find all other nodes that are within distance *d<sub>limit</sub>* of it, reducing the search time from O(N + K) to about O(Log(N) + K).

Unfortunately, once you have determined that B should be joined to A, you cannot eliminate B from further consideration as this would involve removing all nodes of B from the tree, probably a costly operation.

An alternative solution is by gridding: overlay a square grid on the nodes in such a way that every tile contains a few of them.

When you consider some polyline, start from the tiles that contain it and perform successive dilations until you exceed the size *d<sub>limit</sub>*. The tiles in the dilation will tell you what other nodes are close enough.

UPDATE:

You can consider raster-scan the map at a suitable resolution (pixel size = *d<sub>limit</sub>*), using the Bresenham algorithm, every polyline in its own color. You will have to draw with a line thickness of 2 pixels because points in neighboring pixels will be close neighbors. Report all color collisions.

Actually this is a reformulation of the gridding approach. If you can't afford storing the whole map or if this is inefficient due to sparsity, you can consider representing the map as a quadtree. This will trade space for lookup time.

Comment: What is _K_? Gridding is not an option due to the vast size of the area compared to _d-limit_. What do you think of a "join-list", where I only log which multipolylines I will join after I ran through all original multipolylines?

Comment: K is the number of near neighbors reported. In what way does a "join-list" help solve the problem ? What is the point density and how much is Dlimit ? Is the real case truly similar to the toy example ?

Comment: It is a street network and I want to join streets with the same name. The example shows three streets having the same name.

Comment: I'm going with rasterization since it will lead to maximum performance.

Comment: Due to the small relative segment length, you should probably design an ad-hoc version of Bresenham, as most (all?) segments will end up being one to three pixels long.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a fast voronoi diagram. With the polygons you can search for the closest distance.  When you have all edges loop through each site and compute the distance to the edge midpoint. A vd cell divide the sites into 2 equal half. Then sort the distances. It should give you all the polygons and also the nearest neighbors.